# Same Query, Different Results; a Subquery Problem

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am new to SQL. I am coding in SQLite and using the Open Source Chinook Database. I have two queries that from my point of view, they should return the same output; However, the outputs are different. Why am I getting different results for my "SumOfUnitPrice" column?

---

### The ER Diagram for Chinook Database
[image]

Query 1:

```
select tracks.albumid, sum(tracks.unitprice) as SumOfUnitPrice from tracks                
group by tracks.albumid having tracks.albumid in 
    (select albums.albumid from albums where albums.artistid in 
        (select artists.ArtistId from artists where artists.Name = "Audioslave"
        )
    )
```

Result 1:

```
+---------+----------------+                                                                  
| AlbumId | SumOfUnitPrice |                                                                 
+---------+----------------+                                                                  
|      10 |          13.86 |                                                                  
|      11 |          11.88 |                                                                  
|     271 |          13.86 |                                                                 
+---------+----------------+
```

Query 2:

```
select albums.albumid,                                                                  
(select sum(tracks.unitprice)  from tracks                                                
group by tracks.albumid having tracks.albumid in 
    (select albums.albumid from albums where albums.artistid in 
        (select artists.ArtistId from artists where artists.Name = "Audioslave"
        )
    )                                                                                         
) as SumOfUnitPrice                                                                                                                                      
from albums where albums.artistid in                                                    
    (select artists.ArtistId from artists where artists.Name = "Audioslave"
    )
```

Result 2:

```
+---------+----------------+                                                                  
| AlbumId | SumOfUnitPrice |                                                                 
+---------+----------------+                                                                  
|      10 |          13.86 |                                                                  
|      11 |          13.86 |                                                                  
|     271 |          13.86 |                                                                 
+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: And kids, that's the reason why you want to avoid abusing of subqueries. This could be made super explainably with a couple inner joins, why do you need so many subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your subquery within the select block of Query 2 has no relation to the outer one. SQLite will limit the result of the subquery to the first record, which therefore always returns 13.86. In other RDBMS this will cause an exception, that your subquery returns more than one row.

This should provide the same result as Query 1:

```
    select  a.albumid,                                                                  
           ( select sum(t.unitprice)  
             from tracks t
             where t.albumid = a.albumid                                                
             group by t.albumid
           ) as SumOfUnitPrice                                                                                                                                      
    from albums a where a.artistid in                                                    
(select artists.ArtistId from artists where artists.Name = "Audioslave")
```

A much better solution would be to employ joins:

```
    select  t.albumid
            sum(t.unitprice) as sum_of_unitprice
    from tracks  t
    join albums a on a.albumid = t.albumid
    join artists ar on ar.artistid = a.artistid 
    where ar.name = "Audioslave"
    group by t.albumid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is correct in second query your getting query gives you error due to sub query returns multiple records.
You just need to add where clause in second query as below to get same result.
Anyhow best practice of query with joins. as provided by `Dominik Klug`

```
select Outer_albums.albumid,                                                                  
    (select sum(tracks.unitprice)  from tracks                                                
    where tracks.albumid = Outer_albums.albumid
         having tracks.albumid in 
        (select albums.albumid from albums where albums.artistid in 
            (select artists.ArtistId from artists where artists.Name = "Audioslave"
            )
        )                                                                                         
    ) as SumOfUnitPrice                                                                                                                                      
    from albums Outer_albums
     where Outer_albums.artistid in                                                    
        (select artists.ArtistId from artists where artists.Name = "Audioslave"
        )
```